# Oracle DB: default Temp TableSpace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

From [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm)

> "When the SYSTEM tablespace is locally managed, you must define at
>   least one default temporary tablespace when creating a database. A
>   locally managed SYSTEM tablespace cannot be used for default temporary
>   storage."
>
> what is "SYSTEM tablespace is locally managed" ?
>
> which is default temp table space system or temp ?

Thanks

Comment: SYSTEM is where the db stores it's 'stuff.' TEMP is used for doing sorts and other 'math' things. You need a temp tablespace to do that stuff, and most folks will create one called 'TEMP.' All of these things are explained in the Oracle DOCS.

Comment: [Locally managed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/physical.htm#sthref518) is even explained in the same document you linked to. And as it says you *could* still use SYSTEM for TEMP if it's dictionary-managed, but it's not recommended; and lot allowed if it's locally-managed. Look in your data dictionary to see what your actual default temporary table space is, and how your tablespaces are managed.