# Oracle Upgrade 12.2 to 19c Error default temporary tablespace

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to upgrade a database from Oracle 12.2 to Oracle 19c with the help of Database Upgrade Assistent.

In the checks to be fixed there's following error:

> Cause : The following default temporary tablespace does not have an associated temp file.
>
> SYSTEM
> Action : Add at least one temp file to the listed temporary tablespace.

I'm not an Oracle expert, but SYSTEM is **not** a temporary tablespace... So I'm in the dark here as how to fix this error.

The database also **does** have a temporary tablespace named WIKI_TEMP with a tempfile associated to it.

Comment: What is `DEFAULT_TEMP_TABLESPACE` set to in `database_properties`? If that has somehow been set to `SYSTEM` then you might need to change it. Was this database perhaps previously upgraded from 11g or earlier?

Comment: Yes, it is set to SYSTEM... can I set this to something else?

Comment: Yes, but this is off-topic for this site. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32076068/266304) is why I asked about previous upgrades, but only curious. And more into [here](https://www.orafaq.com/node/2), including the `alter` statement to change it; which is also covered [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-DATABASE.html#GUID-8069872F-E680-4511-ADD8-A4E30AF67986).